# How do I update JavaScript when CSS change, without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsiveness

When I change the width of the browser window, I want it to also update the JavaScript. This is because I have made a carousel-slider where JavaScript calculates how much transformation should occur for each sliding image. When I reload the page, the transformation is correct when passing through the images (press of a button). But once I change the width of the browser window, the JavaScript does not seem to update to the new information, and in turn, make the incorrect transformation (the previous width of the carousel-slider, before changing the width). This can be fixed by reloading the page entirely, but this interrupts the flow. I would like my carousel-slider to be responsive and work correctly in real-time when the width of the window changes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: Use the resize event to recalculate your sizes, as Marty points out. You cannot trigger events from changes to CSS though, the browser window changing is a user agent event.

Comment: Instead of calculating the width of the element manually, try using a relative unit. Such as `transform: translateX(-100%)` for the children in the carousel.

Comment: One question you have to ask yourself is, how often do people actively resize their browsers, and does it make sense to be that responsive. A lot of sites design for a certain set of predetermined screen sizes (e.g., large, medium, small) and use media queries to set specific transformations for those sizes.

Comment: Thank you all for the great advice, got it working now! I am using the "resize" event and have also updated the code to use `transform: translateX(-100%)`. I have also begun to implement specific transformations for different media sizes. Thank you all so much!